# Dynamic Arrays for Jquery Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a simple JQuery plugin in which a user can build modules that contain a title, subtitle, and text.

I want to allow the user to be able to add multiple elements to the module in one plugin call.

```
var methods = {
    build : function( options ) {
    var settings = $.extend( {
        'header'    : 'Untitled',
        'subtitle' : 'Subtitle',
        'content' : 'Lorem ipsum dolor amet...',
        'img' : ''  //img URL
    }, options);

    //Create the div to hold elements
    var box = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'service'
    }).appendTo(this);

    //Populate div with header
        $('<h2/>', {
        class: 'service-title',
        text: settings.header
    }).appendTo(box);

    //Check for subtitle
    if(settings.subtitle != 'Subtitle') {
        $('<h4/>', {
            class: 'service-sub',
            text: settings.subtitle
        }).appendTo(box);
    }

    //Add body text
    $('<p/>', {
        class: 'service-text',
        text: settings.content
    }).appendTo(box);

    //Check for image
    if(settings.img != '') {
        $('<img/>', {
            class: 'service-img',
            src: settings.img
        }).appendTo(box);
    }


    },
    add : function() {

    }
};

          $.fn.service = function( method ) {
                if ( methods[method] ) {
                    return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1));
                } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
                    return methods.build.apply( this, arguments );
                } else {
                    $.error( "Method " + method + " does not exist for the Servicer" );
                }
          };
        })( jQuery );
```

In the variable settings, under subtitle, I would like to allow users to add more than one subtitle within one call to .service()

Answer (score 0):

Allow user to make subtitle option an array instead of string. Test if it is a string or array ,if  it is an array run a loop.